# How to echo a variale in html (newbie)

Tags: php

I wan to echo a random swf variable into html, but I can not seem to get the right result.

By checking with firebug I can see that it outputs my php code php echo '$randomImage'

What I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">

.content {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -200px;
    top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<?php

$imagesDir = '/';

$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{swf}', GLOB_BRACE);

$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];

?>


<div class="content"> 
  <center><object width="675" height="517"><param value="<?php echo '$randomImage' ?>" name="movie"><embed width="475" height="317" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="<?php echo '$randomImage' ?>"></object></center><center></center>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: `'$randomImage'` should just be $randomImage or with "`s

Comment: Change your single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: If you are seeing the whole statement `<?php echo '$randomImage'; ?>` in the HTML output that would mean your PHP code is not being parsed. Is this running from a web server? (if you just see `'$randomImage'`, then it is the quoting already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes.

```
<?php echo $randomImage; ?>
```

PHP interprets that as a string rather than the variable `$randomImage`. You can use variables in quotes but they have to be double quotes like so.

```
echo "$randomImage";
```

There is no reason to do this however because you can just echo the variable. This is useful in situations when you want to format a string with multiple variables without concatenation operations.

```
echo "Hello, my name is $myName!, I am a $species.";
```

Which is more simple and readable than the alternative.

```
echo "Hello, my name is ", $myName ,"!, I am a ", $species ,".";
```

Answer (score 0):

You either:

1. Need to use double quotes
2. Can get rid of the qutes altogether

By placing your variable in single quotes you are telling PHP that your dollar sign is to be taken literally and not used to indicate that there is variable.

So use

```
<?php echo $randomImage ?>
```

Or

```
<?php echo "$randomImage" ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To echo properly you should remove the quotes `'$randomImage'` -> `$randomImage` or you can wrap them in "" (double quotes) `"$randomImage"`